# How to determine whether number is exactly representable in floating-point?

Tags: java, floating-point, ieee-754

Since float numbers are base-2 numeral system then it's not possible to represent `0.24F` directly as the same it's not possible to represent `1/3` in decimal system without [recurring decimal period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal) i.e. `1/3=0.3333...` or `0.(3)`.

So the float number `0.24F` when printed back to decimal representation is shown as `0.23` with a change due to rounding:

```
println(0.24F) => 0.23999999463558197021484375
```

while `0.25F` can be shown directly:

```
println(0.25F) => 0.25
```

But how can I determine that a number is exactly representable?

```
isExactFloat(0.25F) ==> true
isExactFloat(0.24F) ==> false
```

Maybe Java API has already some function to do that?

*UPD*
Here is a code which shows float numbers in range [-4, 4] with their internal representation:

```
public class FloatDestructure {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal dec = BigDecimal.valueOf(-4000L, 3);
        BigDecimal incr = BigDecimal.valueOf(1L, 3);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8000; i++) {
            double dbl = dec.doubleValue();
            floatDestuct(dbl, dec);
            dec = dec.add(incr);
        }

    }
    static boolean isExactFloat(double d) { return d == (float) d; }

    static void floatDestuct(double val, BigDecimal dec) {
        float value = (float) val;
        int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(value);
        int sign = bits >>> 31;
        int exp = (bits >>> 23 & ((1 << 8) - 1)) - ((1 << 7) - 1);
        int mantissa = bits & ((1 << 23) - 1);
        float backToFloat = Float.intBitsToFloat((sign << 31) | (exp + ((1 << 7) - 1)) << 23 | mantissa);
        boolean exactFloat = isExactFloat(val);
        boolean exactFloatStr = Double.toString(value).length() <= 7;
        System.out.println(dec.toString() + " " + (double) val + " " + (double) value + " sign: " + sign + " exp: " + exp + " mantissa: " + mantissa + " " + Integer.toBinaryString(mantissa) + " " + (double) backToFloat + " " + exactFloat + " " + exactFloatStr);
    }
}
```

When mantissa is zero then the float is definitely exact. But in other cases like `-0.375` or `-1.625` it's not so clear.

Comment: is `0.23999999463558197021484375` really recurring?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Are you asking about the rational number 24/100, or about the result of rounding it to a binary fraction with a 24 bit significand. The latter is, by definition, a terminating binary fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share this function here.

```
// Determine whether number is exactly representable in double.
// i.e., No rounding to an approximation during the conversion.
// Results are valid for numbers in the range [2^-24, 2^52].

public static boolean isExactFloat(double val) {

    int exp2 = Math.getExponent(val);
    int exp10 = (int) Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(val)));

    // check for any mismatch between the exact decimal and
    // the round-trip representation.
    int rightmost_bits = (52 - exp2) - (16 - exp10);

    // create bitmask for rightmost bits
    long mask = (1L << rightmost_bits) - 1;

    // test if all rightmost bits are 0's (i.e., no rounding)
    return (Double.doubleToLongBits(val) & mask) == 0;
}
```

Edit: the above function could be even shorter

```
public static boolean isExactFloat(double val) {

    int exp2 = Math.getExponent(val);
    int exp10 = (int) Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(val)));

    long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(val);

    // test if at least n rightmost bits are 0's (i.e., no rounding)
    return Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(bits) >= 36 - exp2 + exp10;        
}
```

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/tSgGWV)

Answer (score 3):

In general, this is not possible.
As soon as the number is converted to a float or double, it is just an approximation of the number. So your input to isexactfloat() would not be exact...

If you have the exact version of floating point number in e.g. string format, then it would be possible to devise a function that could tell you if the float or double exactly represents the string formatted number or not. See the comment below by Carlos Heurberger on how to implement such a function.

Comment: function: `(String text) -> { var v = new BigDecimal(text); return v.equals(new BigDecimal(v.doubleValue()));}`

Comment: Ok, I spoke too soon and will thus throw an InsufficientJavaKnowldegeException.

Comment: but your answer is pretty useful - it's the way to go (IMHO)! (no Exception thrown)

Comment: @Carlos: I assume that it is safer to use `compareTo` instead of `equals`. The BigDecimal generated from the string *could* have a different scale than the BigDecimal from the double value. `equals` requires same scale, while `compareTo` doesn't.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis true! Well noted, especially if you have extra zeros in the fractional part in the string (not tested)

Answer (score 2):

Java `double` can only represent terminating binary fractions. Doing the conversion to `double` may hide issues, so I think it is better to work from the `String` representation. The conversion to `BigDecimal` is exact if the String represents a number. So is conversion from `float` or `double` to `BigDecimal`. Here are test functions for exact representation as `float` or `double`:

```
  public static boolean isExactDouble(String data) {
    BigDecimal rawBD = new BigDecimal(data);
    double d = rawBD.doubleValue();
    BigDecimal cookedBD = new BigDecimal(d);
    return cookedBD.compareTo(rawBD) == 0;
  }

  public static boolean isExactFloat(String data) {
    BigDecimal rawBD = new BigDecimal(data);
    float d = rawBD.floatValue();
    BigDecimal cookedBD = new BigDecimal(d);
    return cookedBD.compareTo(rawBD) == 0;
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this code works. I've tried it for various numbers. For instance try "0.24375". The code says this number is not exactly represented as a double. However when I print the number in java to 18 (actually more than possible) decimal places I get 0.243750000000000000. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `BigDecimal` from it and catch `java.lang.ArithmeticException` which it will throw if there is a non-terminating decimal expansion.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether your issue has to do with precision (representing 0.24 accurately) or recurring numbers, like 1 / 3.0.

In general precision issues will always creep in if you use the conventional floating point representations.

If precision is a real problem for you, you should look at using [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). While not as flexible as `double` it has other advantages like arbitrary precision, and you can also control the rounding behaviour in non-exact calculations (like recurring decimal values).

If all you are after is precision control, you might want to look at the Apache Commons Math [Precision](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/util/Precision.html) class.

Comment: 0.24 is just as much a recurring binary fraction as 1/3.0

Comment: Yes. But the question has more to do with what is the problem the OP really wants to solve. 1/3.0 is recurring decimal not just binary, so you can never represent it accurately in decimal. If he wants to detect those cases it is a slightly different problem than binary precision issues.  When you do `double d = 1 / 3.0` you obviously expect the recurring issue, while when you do `double d = 0.24` you might not expect it. If the user inputs `0.24` and suddenly gets a different number it is a different use case, and `BigDecimal` helps. As I said in my answer, precision issues will always occur.

Answer (score -1):

You could just compare the `double` and the `float`?

```
public static boolean isExactFloat(double d, float f) {
    return d == f;
}
```

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/41N194)**

Comment: There are numbers whose nearest representations in `float` and `double` are equal but that are not exactly representable in `float`.

Comment: the func can be simplified: boolean isExactFloat(double f) { return f == (float) f; } but the passed value should be a double

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes I thought there was going to be problems with comparing `double` and `float` *exactly*; but thought this solution might work in the OPs scenario.